# JQuery UI - How do you do multiple toggles from a listBox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a listbox in a form, and based on the answers within I want to open a different toggle, using JQuery UI's toggle effect: http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggle/. The code is visible under **'view source'**.

**Part 1**: the code in current form does not support multiple toggles on one page. How can I rewrite the javascript and id the divs differently so multiple toggles respond to multiple links?

**Part 2**: how can I then take a listbox (like below) and get the three options to select from among two toggled divs?

```
<select class="toggle inputBox listBox" id="select" name="customer[option]"> 
  <option>Choose Your Option</option> 
  <option value="1" rel="toggle[one]"> Option 1</option>
  <option value="2" rel="toggle[one]"> Option 2</option>
  <option value="3" rel="toggle[two]"> Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on your question, but if you just want a different animation based on the selected option you can do something like this

### HTML

```
<div>Hey, what?</div>
<select>
    <option>-</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

### jQuery

```
$('select').change(function() {
    switch (this.selectedIndex) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        $('div').fadeOut(300, function() {
            $(this).show();
        });
        break;
    case 2:
        $('div').slideUp(300, function() {
            $(this).show();
        });
        break;
    }
});​
```

### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/HJYYj/

### Edit

Just read your question and understood that you want to hide a different element with each option. You can modify the above jQuery pretty easily for that.

**Updated Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/yrNjS/

**Updated Code**

```
$('select').change(function() {
    switch (this.selectedIndex) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        $('span').slideUp(500, function() {
            $(this).show();
        });
        break;
    case 2:
        $('div').slideUp(500, function() {
            $(this).show();
        });
        break;
    }
});​
```

Comment: Hi Robert, I noticed that the toggles flip back right after I select an option with the drop down box. Why don't they stay in place after being selected?

Comment: The callback function (`$(this).show();` right after the `slideUp` part) is there so you can redo the animation without having to rerun the script. You can just remove the callback function and they'll stay hidden.

Answer (score 0):

1: When you use the HTML `id` attribute, you must guarantee that no other HTML element on the page has the same ID. You can either use a different `id` for each toggle:

```
$('#id1').toggle(...);
$('#id2').toggle(...);
$('#id3').toggle(...);
```

...or use the `class` selector to apply the same toggle effect to all 3:

```
$('div.toggle').toggle(...); //set all 3 to the same state
```

2: Bind an event listener to the select control. When the select is changed, you can change the state of the toggles by calling `toggle()` again (look at how `runEffect()` is implemented in the example). A couple of the jQuery tutorials have good explanations of how to bind events:

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials